# Getting an error while trying sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, repository

I was trying to install dotnet using this as link as guide, [Install the .NET Core SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1904)

But after inputting this command,

```
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

And trying to update, using this command,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It gave me this error.

```
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/directhex/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Err:7 https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release xenial InRelease        
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B02C46DF417A0893
Reading package lists... Done                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/directhex/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B02C46DF417A0893
E: The repository 'https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It would really awesome if I can successful install the dotnet-sdk, but if that's a problem, I just want to know how not to get this error while updating(No worries about the sdk).

By the way, I'm on Kubuntu 18.04.

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

Comment: That is about a different error, not the same as me.

Comment: This question is about a year old, I don't really know what will fix it anymore.